# FixedResolutionViewport in flame changes the click/touch location

Tags: flutter, camera, viewport, flame

I've been experimenting with the example drag_events game from the flame documentation:

https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/flame/inputs/drag_events.html

Now, I'd like the game to have a fixed size, as this helps with some other aspects of the game that I'm writing.  So, I've modified the code in the Demo by adding the following line to the `onLoad` method:

```
camera.viewport = FixedResolutionViewport(Vector2(400, 800));
```

Unfortunately, the result of this is that the on-screen click appears in the wrong location.  That location depends on the size of the window in which the game is running (and is different again on an iOS simulator).  The image is an example of that for a macOS app.  Presumably there's some simple option which avoids this issue?
[image: Screenshot showing mouse pointer different from click location]

**Edit:** Following Spydon's answer (thank you) it is fixed. The `drag_events.dart` routine now has an `onLoad` function which begins with the following:

```
world = World();
cameraComponent = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(
  world: world,
  width: 400,
  height: 800,
);
cameraComponent.viewfinder.anchor = Anchor.topLeft;
addAll([world, cameraComponent]);
world.addAll([
  DragTarget(),
```

And after that is the same as before.  This solves the offset problem and the new background fills the screen appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an unfortunate side effect that happened when we swapped to the new event system. Use the `CameraComponent` instead (which will be replacing the `Camera` in `FlameGame` anyways) and it will work:

```dart
class CameraComponentExample extends FlameGame {
  late final CameraComponent cameraComponent;
  late final World world;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    world = World();
    cameraComponent = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(
      world: world,
      width: 400,
      height: 800,
    );
    addAll([world, cameraComponent]);
  }
}
```

And then you add all your components to `world` instead of directly to the game.

Comment: Thanks.  Definitely helped, but seems to have a residual issue (see edited description).

Comment: The default anchor of the viewfinder of the `CameraComponent` is center, so 0,0 is in the center. Set it to `topLeft` if you want it to behave like the old camera:
cameraComponent.viewfinder.anchor = Anchor.topLeft

Comment: I still have this issue when I apply a visibleGameSize to the viewFinder. Is there a way to easily adjust the touch position? (right now I compute the position depending on the canvaSize)